# Is Sub-sonic code-generation for DAL only?

Tags: subsonic, code-generation

I am curious and confused.  Is Subsonic only for or primarily for DAL?

Can it be used to create say a ViewModel or View code for a WPF project or is it only for code generation for the Database.

Also can it be used with/for Entity Framework and/or nHibernate.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Summary) is a code generation tool that will create a DAL for you.

It will not create a ViewModel or a View code for you, though you probably *could* create [templates](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Creating_Your_Own_DAL) for both.

It should **not** used with EF or nHibernate - both a ORMs and will generate their own DAL.

> We're not as complete as NHibernate, but you'll work faster with less concept count. We're not as deep as Linq to SQL, but you can use our stuff on most databases.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have a follow-up question.  Is it similar to Codesmith?

Comment: @Pranav Shah - similar in that it is a code generator. Not similar, in that it is geared towards DAL generation and isn't as multi-purpose.

Comment: Thanks that does clarify things for me.